# Wordpress Woocommerce Subscription - Get Total Active Subscriptions By Product

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

We are building a simple dashboard status plugin that will show the total "Active" subscriptions for a specific product.

I'm using the following function to grab the total active subscriptions, but the numbers aren't lining up due to switched subscriptions. How do I account for the switch subscriptions?

```html
function get_active_subscriptions_count( $product_id) {
  global $wpdb;

  // return the active subscriptions for a defined product ID
  return $wpdb->get_var("
      SELECT COUNT(p.ID)
      FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS p2 ON p.post_parent = p2.ID
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS pm ON p2.ID = pm.post_id
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi ON pm.post_id = woi.order_id
      LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
      WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'shop_subscription' 
      AND p2.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND woi.order_item_type LIKE 'line_item'
      AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
      AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id'
      AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'
      AND p.post_status LIKE 'wc-active'
  ");
}
```

What can I do to account for the switch subscriptions? What am I missing in the query?